# Cross label of checkbox when checked

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, primeng

How can I use CSS to cross the label of a checkbox of Primeng when I check it :

```
<p-checkbox value="test" label="test"> </p-checkbox>
```

**My checkbox :**

[image]

**Needed checkbox :**

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div _ngcontent-taj-c2="" class="ui-g-11" style="padding: 0%;margin: 0%">
  <p-checkbox _ngcontent-taj-c2="" id="a" value="t.name" ng-reflect-value="t.name" ng-reflect-label="test">
    <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget" ng-reflect-ng-class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
      <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" name="undefined" value="t.name">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-cor" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable" ng-reflect-klass="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="ui-chkbox-label ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">test</label>
  </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: share your rendered html

Comment: @Bhuwan i added html generated in browser

Comment: is any class adds in `label` `ui-chkbox-label` when checked. If yes, then use `.added-class-name {text-decoration: line-through;}`

Comment: @Bhuwan i'm not expert in css, can please provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) of Checkbox you will see it has `ui-label-active` class which you can use.

```
::ng-deep .ui-label-active  {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

It's important to add ::ng-deep to be able to access the element from your component.

If you want to change it globally, you can just put it on `styles.css`. Just make sure that it's imported after the primeng styling (In angular.json)

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

styles.css

```
.ui-label-active    {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

style p-checkbox with css property  `text-decoration: line-through;` when it checked